# Importing DatetimeOffset Data into Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I load DatatimeOffset Data into Snowflake the offset defaults to the Timezone of America/Los_Angeles.

The only question I have besides this is how we maintain the provided UTC offset with our TIMESTAMP_TZ fields?

I have also tried copying Data containing a TIMEZONE_TZ into another table and the offset does not get overwritten. It only seems to happen when you import data from an external source.

[Source Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMIXE.png)

[Snowflake Table Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcHGj.png)

[Importing Data into Snowflake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhBLO.png)

[Target Snowflake Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xycVC.png)

I expect the data being imported into Snowflake to retain the existing Datatimeoffsetand not be overwritten by the Snowflake Table.

I also tried using the TIMEZONE_LTZ and had the same error.

Edited to include screenshots of the issue.

Comment: Bad news clue: When trying to unload a TZ column to parquet I got the following: Error encountered when unloading to PARQUET: TIMESTAMP_TZ and LTZ types are not supported for unloading to Parquet.

Comment: I also tried loading TZ data from a CSV file, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about the differences between [TIMESTAMP_LTZ , TIMESTAMP_NTZ , TIMESTAMP_TZ](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#timestamp-ltz-timestamp-ntz-timestamp-tz).

You have to use the one of the three that suits your requirements.  From your example it seems you are mixing them.  Of course you can have both TZ and NTZ columns, but TZ time offsets are destoyed by converting to anything else, eg. casting to `TIMESTAMP` during `COPY into <table>`.

`TIMESTAMP` depends on the [TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#timestamp-type-mapping) parameter and defaults to `TIMESTAMP_NTZ`, which has no timezone offset.

If you want to retain mixed offsets you have to use `TIMESTAMP_TZ`, eg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T AS
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019-10-29 02:58:23.123-05:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM') T
  UNION ALL
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019-10-28 23:58:23.123-08:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM');
```

(Side note: don't use `UNION` above, the two timestamps are the same time in different zones and will become one)

So: Use `TIMESTAMP_TZ` if you want to retain different offsets, use `TIMESTAMP_LTZ` if you want to convert everything to the session `TIMEZONE` and use `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` if you don't want offsets (will possibly be displayed as UTC/Z if you use a timezone format).

Comment: Hi Hans, 

Thanks for the response.

I updated my Question to include a correctly formed table creation script screenshot making it clearer that we are using TIMEZONE_TZ. I also tried TIMEZONE_LTZ and had no success.

Comment: @MatthewAylward be careful with including screenshots of text at stackoverflow instead of the real text, as I've seen people being downvoted into oblivion over this formality.

Comment: it seems the data being imported is only a problem when the data is imported as a parquet file. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Timezone of the timestamp data is governed by the value set to parameter TIMEZONE and its default value is 'America/Los_Angeles'. You could check the same with below query.

```sql
show parameters like '%timezone%';
```

To set it to UTC, run the below query.

```sql
alter account set timezone = 'UTC';
```

This parameter can be set at account level, session level and user level. Refer the link below for more details.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#timezone

Comment: Thanks, Shashi for the response!

My problem relates to the data losing the attached offset when being imported. It should uphold this Data no matter what the Timezone of the Snowflake Db is correct?

I edited my question to include screenshots to clarify my question.

Comment: @MatthewAylward, In that case, I suggest storing the data as string. You could cast it into timestamp for any processing using '::timestamp'. In this way the offset values can be retained.